# FLUIDS AND RIGID BODY DYNAMICS

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

the question says that a door of 1*1 is hinged at its mid point and fluid is filled on its left side what force must be applied such that the gate is held stationary.

IN this my solution is attached with in , I took  torque due to fluid on both the sides of hinge, upper and lower and equated it with the torque that must be applied on the gate at the bottom point such that the gate is held stationary

[image: PART 1 OF MY SOLUTION]

[!2ND PART OF MYSOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urgtr.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urgtr.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.